# Project only required shapefiles in folder

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system

I have 8 shapefiles in a folder with shapefile 1 and 8 in the same projection and the others (shapefile 2-7) if different projections.

Is there a way to use python to use shapefile 1 as the projection template to project shapefiles 2-7 in a new folder but also to only copy shapefiles 1 and 8 in the output folder without reprojection them but also not using hard values to keep the script flexible?

I have been trying to use batch project, but am having trouble excluding shapefiles 1 and 8, or only including shapefiles 2-7. Should I be using the Describe.SpatialReference to filter out?

Comment: You should use the Desctibe.SpatialReference to test the projection of the shape file and project only the one that have not the same SpatialRef

Comment: S_TssG, have you an example code of how this is achieved? This is my code, it is saying achieved, but also projecting everything, but there are no shapefiles in the output folder.

Answer (score 1):

this is how I identified different projections. Keep in mind that depending on different datum you need the right transformation. You would need elif for each transformation.

```
for lyr in lyrlist:
    if lyr.visible == True:
        desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr)
        Ref = desc.spatialreference.name
        if "ETRS" in Ref:
            arcpy.Copy_management(...)
        elif "DHDN" in Ref:
            arcpy.Project_management(lyr,desc.path+os.sep+ +desc.basename+"proj.shp","PROJCS['MV32_ETRS_1989_UTM_Zone_32N',GEOGCS['GCS_ETRS_1989',DATUM['D_ETRS_1989',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',32500000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',9.0],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]","DHDN_To_ETRS_1989_8_NTv2")
```

Comment: could you describe what "ETRS" and "DHDN" are?

Comment: These are parts of the name of the projection, just to identify the datum of the projection. The name of the datum is in most cases part of the name of the projection. Of course you have to adapt it to the projections you are using. Sadly the Describe() method does not support the .datumName with projected reference systems. http://help.arcgis.com/de/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v000000p6000000

Comment: yeah, datumName would be nice.  Thanks for the explanation.  You might be able to simplify the `elif` situation by creating a dictionary like `trans = {"ETRS":"transformation 1","DHDN":"transformation 2", etc.}` and then looping through the keys and `if key in Ref:` do the `Project_management` using `trans[key]` for the transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to project first;

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

try:    

inFolder = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()  
template = arcpy.GetParameteAsText(1)  
outFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)


desc = arcpy.Describe(template).spatialReference


arcpy.BatchProject_management(inFolder, outFolder, desc)  

except:  
arcpy.AddMessage (arcpy.GetMessages ())

for fc in fcList:    
print fc
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your code this way :

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

inFolder = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()  
template = arcpy.GetParameteAsText(1)  
outFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)


srf= arcpy.Describe(template).spatialReference

for fc in fcList:    
 if arcpy.Describe(fc).spatialReference.name != srf.name:
  arcpy.Project_management (fc, outFolder + "\\" + fc, desc, {transform_method}, {in_coor_system})
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts S-TssG. For some reason I get an error in line 19 <module>                                        desc = arcpy.Describe(template).spatialReference                      AttributeError: DescribeData: Method spatialReference does not exist. Do you know much about the error message?

Comment: What is your version of ArcGIS ?

Comment: I edited the code could you try again ?

Comment: I'm using 10.3, ahhh, now it doesn't like line 16. template = arcpy.GetParameteAsText(1)

Comment: I am using the script in a toolbox inArcGIS to run. I have set parameters as workspace, Feature Class and Folder. Is this correct?

Comment: insert "arcpy.AddMessage(template)" just before using the first describe and tell me if the path to the feature class is correct

Comment: OK the path is correct and working, but for some reason not filtering out the 2 shapefiles as outlined in the Describe. I am guessing that != means not equal too, something you have taught me :).

Comment: The shapefiles you want to list are in the workspace ?

Comment: Yes, there are 8 shapefiles in the workspace, 2 in the same projection and I am using 1 of those as the spatial reference template. There should only be 6 being projected into the output folder.

Comment: Are you sure the 6 shapefiles have a projection (.prj file with them) ?

Comment: yeah, all 8 files have the projection with them.

Comment: I see here : https://geonet.esri.com/thread/35690 that you may have to reboot your arcgis and try again. 

Sorry i don't see any other solution...

Comment: No change, still all 8 files being projected. Thanks for all you time and help, its really appreciated as I am new to python, which I'm sure you picked up.

Comment: I haven't understand the script was working : i edited it. teel me if it's working

Comment: its working as in projecting all shapefiles in the workspace, but it isnt filtering out shapefiles specified in the if statement :(.

Comment: I edited my script in the answer, tell me if it's working

Comment: nope, script finished quickly with no outputs, I saw you added.name.