# Project only required shapefiles in folder - update

Tags: python

I have updated the script from my previous question;

[Project only required shapefiles in folder](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141975/project-only-required-shapefiles-in-folder)

I can't get the `if fcspatialRef != spatialRef:` to work. The script won't filter the shapefiles in ArcGIS, any advice/suggestions?

```
import arcpy

# Set Workspace  
arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

#Access shapefiles  
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

try:
# Projection template   
  template = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)  
# Output folder  
  outFolder = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

# Get the spatial reference  
 spatialRef = arcpy.Describe(template).SpatialReference 

 #Loop through shapfiles in folder and reproject  
 for fc in fcList:  
    fcspatialRef = arcpy.Describe(fc).SpatialReference  
    if fcspatialRef != spatialRef:      
        arcpy.Project_management(fc, outFolder + "\\" + fc, spatialRef)

# Return any errors   
except:
    arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages ())

# Print shapefile list  
for fc in fcList:  
    print fc
```

Comment: What is your question?  Why shouldn't this be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: Oh sorry, I cant get the if fcspatialRef != spatialRef: to work. The script won't filter the shapefiles in ArcGIS, any advice/suggestions?

Comment: Hi Pete, can you please update the question to be clearer as to what you're asking. If your question isn't clear, it's unlikely you'll get any useful answers.

Comment: Yes Vince, that's me from yesterday, but the script doesnt work in ArcGIS. The spatial reference isnt working. S_TssG was helping me.

Comment: Hi Pete, maybe you should consider registering as it would allow you to easily edit any previous questions with new information. And also because this is an awesome forum :)

Comment: Welcome to the site Pete.  It appears that you created two profiles.  Please see the following instructions on how to merge the accounts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts.  Also, it is preferable to edit your original question rather than to open a new one to clarify the first.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [spatial reference](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z0000000v000000) `name` method will likely work for you.

```
 # Get the spatial reference  
 spatialRef = arcpy.Describe(template).SpatialReference.name 

 #Loop through shapfiles in folder and reproject  
 for fc in fcList:  
    fcspatialRef = arcpy.Describe(fc).SpatialReference.name  
    if fcspatialRef != spatialRef:      
         arcpy.Project_management(fc, outFolder + "\\" + fc, spatialRef)
```